# Solidity Can't withdraw Ether out of Contract Mist Browser

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, contract, etherscan

I'm trying to store Ether inside a Contract and refund it when I call the function paypackEther(). Inside of the Remix IDE with the JavaScript VM it works perfectly, but when I execute it on Rinkeby or Ropsten with Mist, I can't get the stored ether. It's making me crazy...

When calling the function "paybackEther" with Mist the [Input Data](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x70b1860a8f1c9f2ec002e737744198a83f8d8182c6b853895991ffceec6201f9) is just "0x" (says Etherscan).
I tried it with multiple computers, but the result stays the same, so I'm really sure it has to do something with my code.

Other code for receiving Ether works perfectly, for example https://github.com/PaulRBerg/contractz/blob/master/contracts/Escrow.sol#L42
(Contract Destructible, fuction destroy)

What's my mistake?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract SimpleContract {


    function () public payable  {
    }

    constructor() payable  public {
    }

    function paybackEther() public  {
        selfdestruct(msg.sender);
    }

}
```

The contract adress is: 0x0b5933fd3D33F7d79C0e19e12A070fafA053Df57 https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x0b5933fd3d33f7d79c0e19e12a070fafa053df57

There you can also see all my transactions. I published the code.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It would also be interessing if this code is working on your computers...?

Answer (score 0):

To debug this issue, maybe create the below method and see what amount its returning. I doubt, if the amount is leaving your balance in the first place (or maybe you might be sending amount in wei instead of sending it in ether).

```
    function getBalanceOfContract() public view returns (uint){
       return address(this).balance;
    }
```